# Is there a possibility to print supports that have overhang themselves?

Tags: support-structures

I've been looking for various ways to cut down on material costs in my 3D prints. One of them is reducing material in supports, or trying to get rid of supports completely. I do not have a question on how to reduce by changing settings regarding the supports but rather the shape of the supports.

I have an old Creality Ender 3, but it has no issues with printing +/-45° overhangs. Cura generates pretty much vertical supports for anything above a 45° angle, which makes sense. but would it be possible to have a slicer generate support where the walls of said support have overhangs themselves? Another way of putting it, the bottom of the support has a small surface and slowly expands upwards to the size of the roof that it is supporting. As long as the angle is under 45° this should be sturdy, but cut down significantly on support material.

[image: Screenshot of Cura's Preview showing the support material on a model where the support material itself has overhangs]

I tried the other support option Cura offers (tree) but it's nowhere near what I mean. I feel like I'm on to something I just wouldn't know how to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for Cura's "Conical Support" option, which I believe is still classified as "experimental" and not shown by default, but works great in my experience. Search for it and make it visible if it's not visible by default in your version of Cura.

The other option is using tree supports. These will naturally have overhangs (up to "Support Tree Angle"), but differ in lots of other ways that can make them a lot better or some what worse than "classic" supports depending on what you're trying to print.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully printed several things on a Creality Ender 3 V2 with Marlin 2.x firmware using the newly supported [Tree Supports using the free Ultimaker Cura Slicer 5.5](https://ultimaker.com/learn/tree-supports-what-are-they-and-how-do-they-work/) as shown below:

[image: Tree Support]

Those supports are basically all overhangs and very easy to remove afterwards.